# Can a subquery be used in an Oracle ALTER statement?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Given a table name and a column name, I'm trying to dynamically drop an Oracle constraint that I don't know the name of ahead of time.

I can find the constraint name with this query:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME 
 FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS 
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' AND 
 COLUMN_NAME='MyColumn' AND POSITION IS NULL
```

My first thought was to use a subquery, but that doesn't work and results in an ORA-02250 error:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
  DROP CONSTRAINT (
   SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' AND 
    COLUMN_NAME='MyColumn' AND POSITION IS NULL)
```

So far, the only working solution I have is the following, but it feels unnecessarily complex:

```
DECLARE 
statement VARCHAR2(2000);
constr_name VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME INTO constr_name 
   FROM USER_CONS_COLUMNS 
   WHERE table_name  = 'MyTable' AND 
   column_name = 'MyColumn' AND position is null;
   statement := 'ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP CONSTRAINT '|| constr_name;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(statement); 
END;
/
```

Is there a way to do this with a subquery, as I originally intended?  If not, can anyone suggest a more concise way to do this?

Comment: If there are multiple constraints on the column, you can do a for i in (select) loop ... end loop instead, and catch multiples, but other than that, I'm going with the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot.  SQL and DDL are basically two separated languages.  Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To drop multiple check constraints...

```
declare
i number;
begin
for I in (select CONSTRAINT_NAME from USER_CONS_COLUMNS B where B.CONSTRAINT_NAME in (
select a.constraint_name from USER_CONSTRAINTS a where a.TABLE_NAME = 'MAHI' and a.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'C')
AND B.COLUMN_NAME in ('EMP_NAME','EMP_SAL')) 
LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('alter table DIM_CHR_LOV DROP CONSTRAINT '|| I.CONSTRAINT_NAME);
end LOOP;
end;
```