# How to write sql statement to restore 11g oracle database user's password

Tags: database, oracle

In Oracle 11g, I know I can do the following:

```
select spare4 from user$ where name='BOB';
```

and get

```
'S:06A5CA37447558898739F8475FB32C4E4267AD4615F93BD3443028FDB8D6'
```

Then I can do

```
alter user BOB identified by values 'S:06A5CA37447558898739F8475FB32C4E4267AD4615F93BD3443028FDB8D6'
```

to restore the password.
How can I combine them together, the following will not work?

```
alter user BOB identified by values (select spare4 from user$ where name='BOB');
```

with the error

```
alter user BOB identified by values (select spare4 from user$ where name='BOB')
                                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02153: invalid VALUES password string
```

Also, how to avoid typing the username (here BOB) twice? Ideally, I want to do this `alter` operation for every user in `dba_users`.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a short PL/SQL script to do it:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR R IN (SELECT 'ALTER USER '||name||' IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '''||spare4||'''' AS s FROM user$ WHERE name <> 'ANONYMOUS') LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE R.s;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[You can't use a subquery in DDL.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903632/can-a-subquery-be-used-in-an-oracle-alter-statement)

Comment: Thank you! It is great. Just wonder if you know why for user `ANONYMOUS`, it is not working since its `spare4` is empty. How to modify the script to account for this corner case?

Comment: You can exclude ANONYMOUS in the SELECT statement that drives the loop. Answer updated.

Comment: Sure. But I need to unexpired `ANONYMOUS` since it is currently expired too. How can I do that?

Comment: Change or set the password for ANONYMOUS before running the script to unexpire the password. Then you can remove the WHERE clause in the script as well.

Comment: I am really sorry. But how to leave no password of `ANONYMOUS`? `alter user ANONYMOUS identified by values '';` isn't working, with error `ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kzsviver:1], [], [], [], [], [],
[], [], [], [], [], []
`

Comment: I don't think you can set a null password.

Comment: But isn't `select spare4 from user$ where name='ANONYMOUS';` shows `
SPARE4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
` shows it is empty?

Comment: As far as I know, you must change the password to unexpire it. There's no way I know of to set it to null. It's an Oracle supplied account, I guess they have their ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly write a bit of PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR u IN (SELECT * FROM user$)
  LOOP
    l_sql_stmt := 'ALTER USER ' || name || 
                  ' IDENTIFIED BY VALUES ''' ||
                  u.spare4 ||
                  '''';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I would be rather concerned, though, about anything that changed the password of every user in the database.  It's unusual enough that there is a good reason to change an individual user's password, do something, and then change it back without ever knowing the original password.  I'm hard-pressed to imagine needing to do that to dozens of accounts.